# Find number of complete word in string Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I need to find the number of only complete words in string.

```
let string = "There is a string and string"
```

So when I search for `string` it should return 2.

But when I search for `str`, it should be 0.

Comment: Did you try anything yourself ?

Comment: Yes, I tried to split the sentence and then find the occurrence of the word but I need a more optimal solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the complete word using regex :

```
let sentence = "There is a string and string"
let find = "string"
let pattern = ".*?\\b\(find)\\b.*?"
do {
  let regEx = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
  let nsString = sentence as NSString
  let matches = regEx.matches(in: sentence, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, nsString.length))
  print(matches)
} catch {
   print("Matching failed")
}
```

Comment: Good answer, I have converted your answer into an [extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59011120/5623035) for easier usability.

Answer (score 1):

## Using an extension

```
extension StringProtocol {
    func matchRanges<T: StringProtocol>(of string: T, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions = [], range: Range<Index>? = nil) throws -> [NSTextCheckingResult] {
        let pattern = ".*?\\b\(NSRegularExpression.escapedPattern(for: .init(string)))\\b.*?"
        let regEx = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
        let range = NSRange(range ?? startIndex..<endIndex, in: self)
        return regEx.matches(in: .init(self), options: options, range: range)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
try? string.matchRanges(of: "string").count
```

<sub>You can catch and handle errors if you like</sub>

Comment: You should make your method generic and extend StringProtocol instead of String to support substrings as well

Comment: `extension StringProtocol {
    func matchRanges<S: StringProtocol>(of string: S, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions = [], range: Range<Index>? = nil) throws -> [NSTextCheckingResult] {
        try NSRegularExpression(pattern:  ".*?\\b\(NSRegularExpression.escapedPattern(for: .init(string)))\\b.*?")
            .matches(in: .init(self), options: options, range: NSRange(range ?? startIndex..<endIndex, in: self))
    }
}`

Comment: Thanks @LeoDabus, I changed your provided code a bit and updated my answer. It's way better now. Thanks again.

Comment: Don’t use Self Use a new generic type.  It does make a difference. Believe me.

Comment: try `let sentence = "There is a string and string".dropFirst()
let find = "string"
try! sentence.matchRanges(of: find)` then change to my original implementation and try again

Answer (score 0):

You just have to check space in word and loop over it whichever string you want to find.

```
    let string = "There is a string and string"

    let result = string.components(separatedBy: " ").map({ str -> Int in
        if str == "string" {
            return 2
        }else {
            return 0
        }
    })

print(result)

**Output -** [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2]
```

**0 means** Word is not in string whichever you finding

**2 means** Word is in string whichever you finding